# What makes Swift's "Optional" safer than Objective-C's "nil"?

Tags: objective-c, swift, pointers, option-type

[Apple seems to claim](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional) that the `Optional` type in Swift is safer than `nil` in Objective-C, but I don't understand why this is so.

What are the salient differences in implementation that make `Optional`s safer than `nil`, and how will this affect my code?

Comment: Swift does not support nil outside the use of Optional. An Optional can contain nil, whereas a non-Optional cannot contain nil. If you declare a variable as implicitly unwrapped using "!", if the variable contains nil when you make use of it, you will get an exception. Therefore you don't have to deal with a variable "magically" containing nil when you don't expect it.

Comment: @Michael Your comment works as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always do check if a variable is `nil` before I use it to avoid problems. However, it still happens once in a while that a value might come in as `nil`, to my surprise -- or sometimes I just plain forget to check.

After I code more and more in Swift, I have found that using optional variables indeed provides a lot of convenience to avoid ignoring the checking for `nil` values. I don't really recall any crashes due to `nil` variable access (unless I force the unwrapping of some variable; so don't do force unwrapping unless you know what you are doing).

Besides, I used to write a lot of code like this in many places:

```
if (obj != nil) {
    obj.property = ...
}
```

Now I can simply do it as

```
 obj?.property = ...
```

The code now looks clean and sharp. Don't you like it too?

Comment: That's a pretty bad example, because obj.property = ... works just fine in Objective-C and does nothing.

Comment: I am not referring to Objective-C. It's just a general case for most of the programming languages. Try this in Lua, for example. Crash!

Comment: This question had been changed. When I answered this question, I think the question didn't mention about Objective-C's nil or to compare Swift with Objective-C. This question must be merged or changed. It has lost the original intention.

Answer (score 2):

It becomes "safe" because it forces the programmer to write more explicit code.

- The `if let ...` and `guard` syntax explicitly says "do this only if there are values for these variables".
- The `!` syntax makes the program crash if the variable is `nil` when the programmer did not expect it to be `nil`.

In contrast, Objective-C's way of making calls to `nil` a no-op *may* let the program continue to execute until such point that `nil` is not acceptable. One common example is `nil` `NSString` variables. Many API calls are happy with a `nil` `NSString` except when constructing `NSAttributedString` (it won't accept a `nil` `NSString` parameter and crashed your app). Hence when you get an `NSString` variable unexpectedly becomes `nil`, it may be a while later until your app crashes because it tries to construct an attributed string with that `nil` value.

For a more complete illustration on the problem that Optionals tried to solve, consider [this post back from 2010 by Daniel Jalkut](https://red-sweater.com/blog/1423/dont-coddle-your-code). This was written long before Swift.

Answer (score 2):

In general, in programming we want to avoid variables that have no value (`null` or `nil`) because using them often results in undefined behaviour (exceptions, errors, crashes).

For example, it is a common practice for `Array` references to be set to empty arrays instead of `nil`. On an empty array we can use all the `Array` methods, e.g. `indexOf` or `count`. Using them on `nil` would result in a crash.

Optionals allow us to specify that some variables are never empty, therefore we can use them safely and the compiler checks that `nil` is never assigned to them. Also, the compiler enforces that every conversion from optionals to non-optionals is explicit (we are always checking for `nil` when needed).

So the answer would be that optionals:

1. Enforce good programming practices.
2. Allow for better code checking at compilation time

Thus preventing programming errors.

Also note that the you should always try to avoid optionals when possible. The greatest power of optionals is the fact that most variables are not optionals.

Comment: Could you elaborate your last statement "The greatest power of optionals is the fact that most variables are not optionals."?

Comment: @JoeHuang That's pretty simple. If all your variables are optionals, you are back in the world without optionals. Everything can be `nil`. The power of optionals is to limit `nil` to specific libraries.

Comment: I do think there are more optionals when considering asynchronised programming. I don't get how to make most variables not optionals.

Comment: @JoeHuang Asynchronous programming doesn't have more optionals. It's all about the programming style. Of course, you cannot avoid optionals completely but you should try to minimize their usage, otherwise you are not gaining anything from them.

Comment: "Using _[`indexOfObject:` or `count`]_ on `nil` would result in a crash" Well, not in ObjC.

Comment: Comparing Objective-C and Swift: Calling array methods on a nil array in Objective-C does _not_ crash. indexOfObject returns 0. count returns 0. And so on.

Comment: @JoshCaswell In Obj-C the call won't crash but the result will still be unexpected. For example, `[nil indexOfObject:x]` won't return `NSNotFound`. That was the point I was trying to make. There are some situations when the language is lucky, e.g. `string.length == 0` or `array.count == 0` but there are many situations when the app won't crash but it will result in an unexpected state. One of the most common Obj-C questions on SO: *"My method is not called."*.

Answer (score -2):

In Objective-C, you can define a variable without a value. If you want to use that variable before assigning a value, you will get a undefined behaviour(which is very bad). On contrary, swift prevents the scenario where the value of a object is unknown.

Comment: Since ARC was introduced a few years ago, any pointer to an Objective-C object is automatically initialised to nil. No undefined behaviour. And if you turn on reasonable compilation settings, your code will not compile if you try to use an uninitialised variable.